# DirectShow filter graph never completes on some machines

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directshow

I'm working on a DirectShow filter graph to retrieve `IMediaSample` from a video file. We received the original implementation from a contract developer a while back and I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why this code is working on my development machine but not on two other test servers I have.

As best I can tell the filter graph is never completing on the "broken" machines. I always receive `E_ABORT` from the `IMediaEvent->WaitForCompletion()` call. However on the "working" machine this call generally returns `S_OK` after about two loops.

**Update:** <strike>[DirectShow Spy](http://alax.info/blog/777) doesn't seem to be working for me. Perhaps that's because we have a custom, unregistered, `CTransInPlaceFilter` to collect the `IMediaSample` in the chain? There is no error but both GraphEdit and GraphStudio just hang when trying to connect to the remote graph.</strike> (<-- As suggested message pumping resolved this)

Using [GraphStudio](http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/tools/monogram-graphstudio/) I was able to get the media subtype from the MPEG-4 Decoder that connects to our `CTransInPlaceFilter`. On my machine it's `MEDIASUBTYPE_YV12` but on the "broken" machine it's `MEDIASUBTYPE_IYUV`. In the `CheckInputType` method of our `CTransInPlaceFilter` we only accept `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24` which leads me to believe there is one or more "magic filter" being inserted into the graph.

**Update:** Thanks to Roman R. I was able to get [DirectShow Spy](http://alax.info/blog/777) working. On the "broken" machine at least. On the "working" machine I get an access violation but the filter graph runs quick and is torn down so it's tough to connect to it.

I also found that we had a color space converter that was able to handle `MEDIASUBTYPE_IYUV` in `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24` out. I added that to the graph and it should be correct now.

[DirectShow Spy](http://alax.info/blog/777) shows this as the filter graph (looks complete to me):

```
File Source -> MPEG Demux -> MPEG4 Decoder -> Color Space Converter -> CTransInPlaceFilter -> Null Render
```

However the `IMediaEvent->WaitForCompletion()` call never returns `S_OK` and the filter graph just runs forever. So now I'm stumped as to what is going on. Is there anything else I should be checking for an error state or something?

**Update:** I modified the loop to enumerate the filters in the graph and query their state:

```
char debugString[512];

int count = 0;
long EvCode;
mediaFilter->SetSyncSource(NULL);
hr = mediaControl->Run();

sprintf(debugString, "mediaControl->Run() %d", hr);
DebugLog(debugString);

while (!m_ThreadKill)
{
    hr = mediaEvent->WaitForCompletion(200, &EvCode);

    sprintf(debugString, "mediaEvent->WaitForCompletion() %d, %d", hr, count);
    DebugLog(debugString);
    count++;

    IEnumFilters *pEnum = NULL;
    IBaseFilter *pFilter;
    ULONG cFetched;

    graphBuilder->EnumFilters(&pEnum);

    while(pEnum->Next(1, &pFilter, &cFetched) == S_OK)
    {
        FILTER_INFO FilterInfo;
        FILTER_STATE FilterState;

        char szName[256];

        pFilter->GetState(200, &FilterState);
        pFilter->QueryFilterInfo(&FilterInfo);
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, FilterInfo.achName, -1, szName, 256, 0, 0);

        sprintf(debugString, "Filter: %s, %d", szName, FilterState);

        DebugLog(debugString);

        SAFE_RELEASE(FilterInfo.pGraph);
        SAFE_RELEASE(pFilter);
    }

    SAFE_RELEASE(pEnum);

    if (hr == S_OK)
    {
        break;
    }
}

sprintf(debugString, "mediaControl->Stop()");
DebugLog(debugString);

mediaControl->Stop();
```

They are all in the "Running" state. So if the filter are connected correctly and all the filters are running why does the graph never complete on the "broken" machines?

**Update:** As suggested by Roman R. I removed our `CTransInPlaceFilter` from the filter graph on the broken machine and the graph successfully completed. With the `CTransInPlaceFilter` connected the CPU usage drops to zero. So now I'm not sure why the following code works on some machines but not others. I'll start adding some debug logging to the `CTransInPlaceFilter` to try and figure out what is going on (or not going on).

---

**Solution:** As suggested by Roman R. (I feel like I'm repeating myself :P) the problem ended up being a deadlock. The broken machines all had a single CPU/core where as the working machines had multiple CPUs/cores. The application consists of a thread per source video, a merge thread, and a destination thread.

The source thread(s) run a filter graph (I assume the filter graph also runs in it's own thread) to retrieve the data from an `IMediaSample` and place it into a `CQueue<BYTE*>`.

The merge thread loops through the sources, retrieves the sample data from the source `CQueue<BYTE*>`, merges the frames into a single image, and sends them off to a `CQueue<BYTE*>` the destination thread consumes.

The destination thread runs another filter graph to encode the video/audio.

The `CQueue<BYTE*>` blocks on a Put until there is free space. Normally this is fine because the merge thread is removing items. However on the single CPU/core machines the merge thread was being blocked by the source threads.

Long story short a `Sleep(0);` here and there allowed the source threads to yield to the merge threads and the problem seems to be resolved.

Comment: The code snippet is unlikely to be relevant to the issue. You need to make sure you successfully create filter graph in first place. Then, before running the graph, you need to inspect its effective topology to see what's inside. You are likely to see differences between your systems on this step. Then you will see what makes the streaming incomplete.

Comment: If you see your graph, then spy does work. Spy and graph remoting tools however will freeze if you don't pump window messages while streaming is in progress - so it's more an issue with your code (not fatal, of course, but message pump is a good idea anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playback completion internally includes sending end of stream notifications from the streams sources, which are relayed by downstream filters, gathered on renderers and then, combined, are reported to the application. So, successful completion depends on all participants of the filter graph acting right.

You discovered the topology of your graph, and you need to compare topologies on your different machines. If you see any differences there, they might suggest what filter could be losing completion notifications.

However, even if the topologies match accurately, some filters could act differently for other reasons. In particular, having your own custom filter on the graph has high chances that it is losing the notification and the graph never completes. It stops processing data and just idling from there (this is another thing you want to check - whether CPU consumption lowers to zero or some processing is still happening, in which case you could re-qualify the issue into deadlock).

Something you could more or less easily to to approach this problem is to start cutting filters off the graph to identify which filter exactly brings the problem in. Trying these graphs would possibly find an offender:

```
File Source -> MPEG Demux -> MPEG4 Decoder -> Color Space Converter -> Null Render
File Source -> MPEG Demux -> MPEG4 Decoder -> Null Render
File Source -> MPEG Demux -> Null Render
```

Comment: Ok so that got me somewhere. I removed our CTransInPlaceFilter from the graph and it successfully completed. Still not sure why the filter works on some machine but not other. Question updated with more details.

Comment: You need to check things around `IPin::EndOfStream` on this filter. Something is wrong there.

Comment: As far as I can tell he didn't implement `IPin::EndOfStream` any where and just relied on the base. However I think you might be on to something regarding the deadlock since I only see the `CTransInPlaceFilter::Transform` method called four time and then it just stops. On my working machine I see the method called the appropriate number of times related to the number of frames.

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to say without looking at the whole thing. When I was developping DS filters, I used GraphStudio and [FilterGraph Spy](http://alax.info/blog/777) at lot.

A common mistake is to use "auto filters" which may be not available on target machines. Suppose that your video is h264 and you try to read raw RGB from it, DS will automatically supply decoder filters and color space transforms for you. Many intermediate filters will be generated without you noticing it from your code. This is why it is very important to dump the graph in a visual tool and check how everything is wired.

My guess is that one or more of those "magic filters" do not exist on your deployment server. Something you can try is to use GraphStudio directly on the server and wire everything like you would do programmatically and see how and why it fails from there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll take a look at those tools and see what I can find.